Native American(?) guy whose village is raided
So I saw a movie long time ago, it's kinda new, I think, like 2011 or something.
There's a Native American(?), I'm not sure, but there's a village and some others come and burn it down and they take him and his friends as slaves and kill his family etc... Edit: They don't kill his family!! He hides them in a small cave and the mother is pregnant while they are hiding.
Sorry for the bad description but does anyone know the name of the movie? I think it starts with an G in the title. Not sure though, would appreciate any help :) 

They dont kill his family!! He hides them in a small cave and the mother is pregnant while they are hiding

Sounds like the beginning of Apocalypto from 2006.

While hunting in the Mesoamerican rainforest, Jaguar Paw/Paksiw (Rudy Youngblood), his father Flint Sky (Morris Birdyellowhead), and their fellow tribesmen encounter a procession of refugees fleeing warfare. The group's leader explains that their lands were ravaged and they seek a new beginning. He asks for permission to pass through the jungle. Flint Sky comments to his son that the visitors were sick with fear, and urges him to never allow fear. At rise the next morning the tribe's village is raided by a group led by Zero Wolf (Raoul Trujillo). Huts are set on fire, many villagers are killed, including Flint Sky, and the rest of the adults are taken captive. Jaguar Paw's heavily pregnant wife Seven (Dalia Hernández) and their young son Turtle's Run (Carlos Emilio Báez) escape by hiding in a small natural pit cave that also serves as a water reservoir, but are left trapped when Jaguar Paw is captured. The raiders then lead the captives on a long forced march through the jungle, having left the children behind to fend for themselves.

Here's the trailer:



